# Firefox: How do I disable AddOns on my Mac

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-addons

This morning firefox told me it needed to upgrade an addon (noflash) and I told it to go ahead. Now Firefox won't start.

1. How can I prevent Firefox from loading the addons?
2. Where are the Firefox config files?
3. How to I start Firefox.app from the terminal, so I can pass a parameter?

**UPDATE**
I was able to start Firefox in safe mode by holding down the 'alt' key while clicking on the dock icon. (see my answer below)

so problem 1 (the main problem) is solved .. can anyone help me on 2 and 3?

Comment: I have updated my answer for your 3rd question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key, as you start Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If by config files you mean your profile it is located in your user home directory under the following path (xxxxxxxx is a random string)

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default/.
```

To start firefox from the terminal do the following (see [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments#For_Linux_and_Mac_OS_X_users) for a reference)

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

I clicked the firefox icon in the dock while holding down the 'alt' button. Firefox came up in safe mode and presented me with a dialog where I could disable all addons ..

I now have all addons except noflash (uninstalled) working again and am editing this text using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, you should have "locate" installed (I did on my mac, which I had a few years ago ...) so if you can open a terminal (usually in Applications/Utilities/terminal) you can just say "locate firefox.app" (or even "locate firefox") and it'll find it. Barring that, you can also do:

sudo find / -name "firefox.app"

"find" definitely exists on OSX.

Comment: I'll look for 'locate' or I could write a shell script using **sudo find /  -iname "firefox.app"** thanks for the tip (+1 for that)! **BUT** Alas, I already found  'Firefox.app', I need a way to run it from the command line